# log4j not logging in AIX with websphere

Tags: java, log4j, aix

I have an servlet which should log message with log4j. Under development environment (Windows + Eclipse + tomcat), the log4j is working.

When I deploy the servlet into production (AIX + websphere), it didn't give any log.

I don't know what happened. **What is the possible reason?** The war file was created by eclipse after verify the logging function was working in development environment. I want to gather more clues before I deploy it again in production.

The java program didn't give any clues. I looked up the SystemOut.log, and the log4j loggers were initialized successfully, however, they didn't say anything went wrong about the log files.

I suspect 2 reasons:

1) the logging directory have drwxr-xr-x privileges, may be the java program don't the right to create file there?

2) The log4j.properties files was strange. When I looked it up at AIX via vi, I discovered there was a ^M after every line ending. Probably unix don't need this carriage return character. Maybe this ^M character messed up the things?

EDIT: I found out there are another log file called SystemErr.log. It contained the error message:

> [9/1/11 17:07:43:086 HKT] 00000013 SystemErr     R log4j:ERROR
>   setFile(null,true) call failed.
>
> [9/1/11 17:07:43:086 HKT] 00000013
>   SystemErr     R java.io.FileNotFoundException: /bps/log/BpsPdfBill.log
>   (The file access pe rmissions do not allow the specified action.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does it feel being a servlet? :-)

On topic: if you place your logfile outside of the folders where WAS unpacks your war file, who is the owner? To be able to write to the directory with those permision, the user `was` needs to be the owner (and has to have permission to access the parent folders too.)

The ^M characters are the newlines that are present in DOS/windows, for UNIX thay are whitespace and as such not a problem (just a nuisance) you can add a task in your Ant build file to remove the newlines before you pack the war archive.

Comment: So, my best bet would be set a 777 permission to an external directory, or use a directory inside the war file as log directory?

Comment: @gunbuster363, setting the permission to 777 is easiest but not necessary. If you `chown was:was /bps/log` and make sure that `/bps` has at least `r-x` permissions for the user `was` (or others) you should be ok too.

Comment: I set the directory to 777. It is okay now. Thanks.